# Get the nth character, string, or number after delimiter in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string

In VB.net (Visual Studio 2015) how can I get the nth string (or number) in a comma-separated list?
Say I have a comma-separated list of numbers like so:

> 13,1,6,7,2,12,9,3,5,11,4,8,10

How can I get, say, the 5th value in this string, in this case 12?
I've looked at the Split function, but it converts a string into an array. I guess I could do that and then get the 5th element of that array, but that seems like a lot to go through just to get the 5th element. Is there a more direct way to do this, or am I pretty much limited to the Split function?

Comment: You can use `Split`: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Comment: @Hackerman: He mentioned that....

Comment: Oops, my mistake :)

Comment: you dont have to store the array: `result = csv.Split(","c)(5)`.  pretty simple

Comment: @Plutonix, that is darned simple. I don't recall that particular use of the Split function turning up in any of my Google searches. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: `Get the nth string or number...` A CSV is never going to contain numbers only text.  `Convert.ToInt3290` to convert the result to an actual numeric

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm actually using the result as a string and concatenating it (file & split & .ext),  which I could never do with a number, though I could convert the number to a string and then concatenate the string. That's why I included "numbers" parenthetically.

Comment: @Plutonix, would you be kind enough to put your comment into an answer so that I can mark this as answered?

Comment: You can post a self answer and mark it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by Plutonix as a comment to my question is straightforward and exactly what I was looking for, to wit:

> result = csv.Split(","c)(5)

In my case I was incrementing a variable each time my program ran and needed to get the nth character or string after the incremented value. That is, if my program had incremented the variable 5 times, then I needed the string after the 4th comma, which of course, is the 5th string. So my solution was something like this:

> result = WholeString.Split(","c)(IncrementedVariable)

Note that this is a zero-based variable.
Thanks, Plutonix.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for an alternative method, which is more basic, you can try this:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim a As String = "13,1,6,7,2,12,9,3,5,11,4,8,10"
    Dim counter As Integer = 5 'the number you want (in this case, 5th one)
    Dim movingcounter As Integer = 0 'how many times we have moved
    Dim startofnumber, endofnumber, i As Integer
    Dim numberthatIwant As String

    Do Until movingcounter = counter
        startofnumber = InStr(i + 1, a, ",")
        i = startofnumber
        movingcounter = movingcounter + 1
    Loop

    endofnumber = InStr(startofnumber + 1, a, ",")

    numberthatIwant = (Mid(a, startofnumber + 1, endofnumber - startofnumber - 1))
    Console.WriteLine("The number that I want: " + numberthatIwant)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Edit: You can make this into a procedure or function if you wish to use it in a larger program, but this code run in console mode will give the output of 12.

Comment: This is actually a lot more complicated that simply "result = variable1.Split(","c)(variable2)". The program I'm working on runs at boot and increments a counter. I want to use the counter number to get the corresponding position of a string of random numbers.

Comment: @BillOer  Yes, looking at it in terms of length, this is indeed more complex, but for understanding the way it works and using basic string functions, this is another method to consider. And yes, this will be a bad implementation for a boot time program, where speed is essential, but it is a good and flexible approach for other programs.